# Last two section in uitableview not interacting for click

Tags: uitableview

I'm using `UITableViewController` on `storyboard`. I'm displaying the text on section instead of rows. When I run the code on simulator iphone Retina(3.5 inch) last two sections are interacting properly but when the same code is executed on iphone Retina(4 inch) and iphone Retina(4 inch 64 bit)the last two sections are not interacting. I'm new to iphone development.
Thanks in advance.

[image]

I've checked `autolayout` property as shown in the images. Please let me know where else should I change boundaries.

[image]

Comment: The table view might be going outside of the bounds of container view. Please check auto resizing bounds of your controls.

Comment: Add a border to your `tableView` and see at runtime if your table is actually resized, or not. As @Yogi pointed out, it might be bounds issue. Resizing is the *major* issue in such cases, where touches cannot be intercepted.

Comment: Please let me know where else should i change the bound values so the tableview resizes automatically and let me know where to check auto resizing bounds of control